# Pass data to react routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When transitioning from one react route to another, I can pass strings via URL parameters

```
this.props.history.replace({
  pathname: `${this.props.match.url}/newRoute`,
  search: '?someData=someValue'
})
```

But what if I want to pass something more complex, e.g. a deeply nested JSON object? Is there a way such data can be passed from one route to another **without using Redux**?

The project in question is using react 14.4.2 and react-router 4.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

Passing complex data between routes is usually a bad idea. For example, what happens when the user refreshes the page on the route? When the page reloads, all the app state and whatever you passed through to the route will have been lost.

As a rule of thumb, each route should be capable of gathering or refreshing all of the data it needs from scratch using *only* the information in the url (paths, path params, or query strings).

If that doesn't quite fit with your use case, consider the possibility that this part of your app doesn't need its own bookmarkable route/url, and you're just implementing a transitory UI change which is ok if it gets lost upon page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Example for passing parameter in Route:

```
   <Route path="/:id" component={Child} />

   const Child = ({ match }) => (
      <div>
        <h3>ID: {match.params.id}</h3>
      </div>
   );
```

please refer : https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params

Comment: This has exactly the same shortcoming as using query params

Answer (score 0):

I think possible ways can be:

**1-** By using location state object, we can pass the data into that and it will be available in new page. Issue with this approach will be, after refreshing the new page, that data will not be available.

Like this:

```
this.props.history.replace({
  pathname: `${this.props.match.url}/newRoute`,
  search: '?someData=someValue',
  state: {
    ....
  }
})
```

And access it in new page by: `this.props.location.state`

**2-** Using `localStorage`, set the data into `localStorage` before navigating to new page and then read the same data in new page.

Like this:

```
navigate() {

   localStorage.setItem('data', obj);

   this.props.history.replace({
      pathname: `${this.props.match.url}/newRoute`,
      search: '?someData=someValue',
    })
}
```

I will suggest to use the 2nd approach, its not a good idea of passing big object in route.

Comment: please share the reason for downvote, i will improve :)